# Proof of eigenvector and eigenvalues Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am finding the eigenvector and eigenvalues of a matrix, then I need to prove that Ax= λx where λ is the eigenvalue. Here is my code:

```
    A = [1 1 -1;1 0 -2; 0 0 -1]
    [evecs,evals]=eig(A)
    for i = 1:3
       A*evecs(:,i)== evals(i,i)*evecs(:,i)
    end
```

Here is my output:
        A =

```
 1     1    -1
 1     0    -2
 0     0    -1
```

evecs =

```
0.8507   -0.5257   -0.3015
0.5257    0.8507    0.9045
     0         0    0.3015
```

evals =

```
1.6180         0         0
     0   -0.6180         0
     0         0   -1.0000
```

ans =

```
 0
 0
 1
```

ans =

```
 0
 1
 1
```

ans =

```
 0
 0
 1
```

Why are the ans not all equal to 1 as it should (in order to prove Ax= λx)

Answer (score 2):

The calculations of your eigen solver are performed using finite precision floating point arithmetic. The true eigen values and eigen vectors are not even exactly representable in finite floating point data types.

Check for equality against a small tolerance to allow for this. That is check that Ax - λx is small in absolute value.

Required reading is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).